# How does one register an IP without DCHP?

Tags: networking, dhcp, adhoc

Scenario: I have a Linux computer in AP mode and for whatever reason, I do not have a DCHP server installed. Now, I connect a couple laptops to said AP. How do I tell the AP (computer) that the new devices belong to such-and-such IP address?

Comment: I'm not a networking expert, but I think you simply don't. Either you get a DHCP server and configure a range/address pool on the AP or you configure the connected laptops with a static IP.

Answer (score -1):

DHCP is a method for automatically register machines in a local DNS server. If you are running Linux on the laptops as well, assign an IP address to each of the machines by editing the `hosts`  file.

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts 
add the following line, change the IP address accordingly.
192.168.1.2 laptop1
```

Or, use **NetBIOS Name Service** for Windows and **multicast DNS** for Mac.

Comment: So essentially, there is no registry maintained. All the computers just assume their own IPs and then when the router wants to route traffic, it asks who has what IP?

Comment: @KI4JGT Yes, this is how it supposed to work.

Comment: DHCP manages IP addresses, not hostnames.

Comment: So, what's ARP for? How are its results generated and does the router have an ARP table?

Comment: @KI4JGT ARP provides the translation between IP and MAC addresses while DNS or `/etc/hosts` provide the translation between IP addresses and hostnames. ARP tables are created dynamically during usage. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol#Example